# Grammar error in Reviewer Stats: "Approved 1 edit suggestions"

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, plurals

*We's approved 1 edit suggestions, my precioussss...*

[image]

With apologies [to Jeff Atwood](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105), can we change that small error to "1 edit suggestion"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's fixed now
[image]